# Best way to export any table using Apache2/PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Apache2/PHP has access to all tables/databases on the MySQL server required for the frontend user interface. I would like to create the ability to quickly and securely export any of these tables as CSV without having to create an export module for each individual table.

Currently I have the following

```php
$file = '/tmp/' . $_POST['table'] . '_export.csv';
$table = $_POST['table'];

$sql = 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "' . $file . '"
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
    FROM ' . $table;
$db->query($sql);
file_put_contents('php://output', file_get_contents($file));
unlink($file);
```

This creates an export in `/tmp` for the table export, however, Apache2 does not have permissions to access `/tmp` since `PrivateTmp=yes` and also the permissions of the file that exported is `rw-r-----`.

I have tried changing `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and adding:

```
secure-file-priv = /var/lib/mysql-files
```

Then creating a script run by root (executable by everyone) that moves the files and sets the permissions correctly. However, not only is this not elegant, the `secure-file-priv` doesn't seem to be changing even after restarting MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /tmp/                     |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note: I'm using MySQL 8.0.22 and fixes from other threads don't seem to help.

What would be the best way of doing this?